# Javascript don't work with Materialize-css (rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, materialize

I have a problem with ruby ​​on rails and materialize (javscript connexion ). I have installed https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass and desactive turbolinks. 
For example when I create a drop menu on my html page and when in the javascript file I initialize the drop menu. It does not work as if there was no javascript

in my view (indexCo.html.erb):

```
<div class="container">
<a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
<li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
<li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
<li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
<li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
<li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a> 
</li>
<li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

application.js :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require materialize
$('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
```

application.html.erb :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

I tried with turbolinks or directly importing into application.html.erb with

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css

and

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js

But nothing works, same with parallax or any other elements
Thanks for your help 
and sorry for google translate
bye

Comment: Resolved : add $(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->

Answer (score 3):

Do not deactivate `turbolinks`. Nowhere in the documentation:
https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass
does it say to deactivate `turbolinks`.

You can change the `application.css` to `application.scss` and drop this: `@import "materialize";` in there per the docs instructions or you can create a `custom.css.scss` and drop in the `@import "materialize";`.

Next step and I suspect the reason why you were not getting any behavior is to require `jquery`, just like you required `materialize` like so:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require materialize
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I can understand, missing this step as its not covered in the docs, so it makes it a slight gotcha which can be a wall if you don't think it through calmly and carefully.

Lastly, in that same `application.js` file you drop the final piece from the docs:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require materialize
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same issue and finally figured it out.

Change

```
//= require materialize
```

to

```
//= require materialize-sprockets
```

I'm not sure what the technical difference is, but it worked for me in Rails 5.1.6.